# subset a data set based on compare with another data set in R

Tags: r

Let's say data set 1 :

```
 ID  ITEM  SEQ   TRANS_DATE     EXPIRE_DATE
  1   2002   3  2014-11-27      2015-08-27
  1   2002   4  2015-08-27      2016-08-27
  2   1003   2  2014-11-27      2015-07-03 
  2   1003   3  2015-07-03       2016-07-03 
  2   1003   4  2015-08-03       2016-07-03
```

Let's say data set 2:

```
 ID  ITEM  SEQ   TRANS_DATE     EXPIRE_DATE
  1   2002   3  2014-11-27      2015-08-27
  2   1003   2  2014-11-27      2015-07-03
```

How to subset the data set 1 based on data set 2?
While by different ID, ITEM group, SEQ is greater than what is in data set 2?
Result would be like this:

```
   ID  ITEM  SEQ   TRANS_DATE     EXPIRE_DATE

   1   2002   4  2015-08-27       2016-08-27
   2   1003   3  2015-07-03       2016-07-03 
   2   1003   4  2015-08-03       2016-07-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key='ID')
setDT(df2, key='ID')
i1 <- df1[df2, .I[SEQ > i.SEQ] ,by=.EACHI]$V1
df1[i1]
#   ID ITEM SEQ TRANS_DATE EXPIRE_DATE
#1:  1 2002   4 2015-08-27  2016-08-27
#2:  2 1003   3 2015-07-03  2016-07-03
#3:  2 1003   4 2015-08-03  2016-07-03
```

---

Or

```
setDT(df1)[df1[df2[c(1,3)], SEQ> i.SEQ, on = 'ID']]
#   ID ITEM SEQ TRANS_DATE EXPIRE_DATE
#1:  1 2002   4 2015-08-27  2016-08-27
#2:  2 1003   3 2015-07-03  2016-07-03
#3:  2 1003   4 2015-08-03  2016-07-03
```